# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast. Parameter: create(ChangeNotifierProxyProvider)

Tags: string, flutter, types, null

I don't need a create parameter, i add this because it's required.

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, TempImages>(
          create: (ctx) => TempImages("", "", []),
          update: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => TempImages(
            auth.token as String,
            auth.userId as String,
            previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items,
          ),
        ),
```

I added as String and .toString() method, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
uth.token as String,
auth.userId as String,
```

Looks like one of them is null. Make sure you pass non-nullable values to your TempImages constructor.